# jquery ui draggable scroll not working

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I have a html table, and manual sort(drag and drop row), when draggable enable, scroll not working.

```
$( "#commands tbody" ).draggable({
         scroll: true
    });
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle showing the issue? \

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mu9o8a6r/ , scroll not working on adnroid devices

Comment: Ah, the *on android devices* changes things a lot, sorry no experience there and dont have an android to test with, sorry